# VBA, Outlook, Seeing 'People's Calendars

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I am tring to programmatically (with VBA) to access calendars others share with me. They are listed in my Outlook under 'People's Calendars.' I have searched the Web for this and all the suggestions have done little more than confuse me. How can I get a listing of all the calendars shared to me, and then one calendar in specific, from among the 'People's Calendars'?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the returned values from the following code. It searches for a person by name, same way as when you are typing a recipient into a new email, and then grabs that persons shared calendar and enumerates all shared appointments.

```
Dim _namespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim _recipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim calendarFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set _namespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set _recipient = _namespace.CreateRecipient(name)
_recipient.Resolve

If _recipient.Resolved Then
    Set calendarFolder = _namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(_recipient, olFolderCalendar)
    'This would display the calendar on the screen:
    'calendarFolder.Display

    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Set oItems = calendarFolder.Items
    'oItems is now a set of all appointments in that person's calendar
    'Play on
End if
```

Comment: Thanks. I always get an 'operation failed' on the 'GetSharedDefaultFolder' call. The 'name' I'm using is the person's who shared the calendar wth me. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Make sure you're passing the GetSharedDefaultFolder an Outlook.Recipient object that has resolved, not just a 'name' string.

Comment: I can't get to GetSharedDefaultFolder unless '_recipient.Resolved' was successful, correct? One observation is that in Outlook 2007, 'People's Calendars' does not show up as a Shared folder in the Folder List view. Is that a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem if you've never viewed that person's shared folder before. Only previously viewed shared folders will show up in the little outlook "People's Calendars" section. In general, any resolved contact's calendar can be opened. If they do not share their calendar, then it will simply contain no appointments, but it will still return.

Comment: The solution is working fine for me - the only thing to mention is that VBA does not like the underscore prefixes in variable names (e.g. change `_recipient` to `recipient`). After I have removed them, it was working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets closer. It came from Sue Mosher's outstanding Microsoft Outlook 2007 Programming: Jumpstart for Power Users and Administrators. I hope she doesn't mind.

```
Sub ShowOtherUserCalFolders()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objExpCal As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim objNavMod As Outlook.CalendarModule
    Dim objNavGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As Outlook.NavigationFolder
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim colExpl As Outlook.Explorers
    Dim objExpl As Outlook.Explorer
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objNS = objOL.Session
    Set colExpl = objOL.Explorers
    Set objExpCal = _
      objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer
    Set objNavMod = objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules. _
      GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    Set objNavGroup = objNavMod.NavigationGroups. _
      GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olPeopleFoldersGroup)
    For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders
        Set objFolder = objNavFolder.Folder
        Set objExpl = _
          colExpl.Add(objFolder, olFolderDisplayNormal)
        objExpl.Activate
        objExpl.WindowState = olMaximized
        objExpl.WindowState = olMinimized
    Next
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objNavMod = Nothing
    Set objNavGroup = Nothing
    Set objNavFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set colExpl = Nothing
    Set objExpl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion to help people who may be trying to use the ShowOtherUserCalFolders() code posted here. This code will create multiple hidden instances of outlook which if run many times can eventual bog down your machine. Instead of creating a new Outlook.application you can call the current open one (outlook must be open for this to work).

To do this replace `Dim objOL As Outlook.Application` with `Dim objOL as Object` and `Set objOL = Application` with `Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`

Also make sure you close the objExpCal Explorer as this will also create a hidden instance of outlook, add `objExpCal.Close` to the end of your code.

Comment: Since the code would be run in Outlook, the code is hooking into the existing instance of Outlook, not creating a new one. In no way would the code ForEachLoop posted create multiple instances of Outlook. Outlook is a single-instance class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481398/vba-determining-whether-an-existing-outlook-instance-is-open for further explanation.