# Late Binding to Open Outlook from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm trying to open the Outlook application from Access VBA when the switchboard loads.  I've opened task manager and I can see an instance of Outlook appear for about 5 seconds then close, but I can't get the explorer window to open.  I've been trying to piece together code from [VBA: Determining whether an existing Outlook instance is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481398/vba-determining-whether-an-existing-outlook-instance-is-open) and other sources, but it's just not working.  Any ideas?

And I would like to stick with late bindings so I don't have to worry about object libraries if someone opens with XP.

```
Function OpenEmail()

Dim olApp As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim olFolderInbox As Object
Dim objExplorer As Object

On Error Resume Next

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

If olApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not Open"
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Set objExplorer = CreateObject("Outlook.MAPIFolder")
Set objExplorer = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

objExplorer.Activate

'Set olApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook is the only MS Office application where `GetObject` does the same thing as `CreateObject`. Unlike other MS Office application, `CreateObject` doesn't create multiple instances of Outlook.

Also `olFolderInbox` is an outlook constant. You will have to define it in ACCESS.

Try this

```
Const olFolderInbox As Long = 6

Sub Sample()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim objNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    With olFolder
        '~~> Do what you want
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: added `.Display` inside the With.  Works like a charm.  I really appreciate it!